# Как правильно писать слой бизнес-логики в spring приложении (целесообразно ли использовать статик методы?)?

Tags: java, spring, архитектура, бизнес-логика

Возьмем простой пример. Есть **spring-boot** приложение, в нём должен быть **web-слой**, слой бизнес-логики, слой **DAO**. Слой **DAO** - запрос к бд, вполне написан, он возвращает табличные сущности  по их **id**-шникам. То есть, в приложении есть пакет dao. Есть пакет web - там лежат контроллеры, которые отвечают на некоторые запросы. К примеру

```
@GetMapping("/index")
    public String index() {
         //Здесь некоторый код содержащий бизнес логику
        return "Hello from application"; //Здесь какой-то ответ
    }
```

Предположим, мне нужно в вышеперечисленный контроллер добавить некоторую логику обработки. Я её выношу в отдельный пакет, условно **logic**, где делаю запросы к базам данных, через API dao слоя.
В этом слое у меня, к примеру, должно быть извлечение двух полей из БД, проверка их на **null**, проброс исключения если что-то пойдет не так.

**Вопрос:** нормальным ли будет стиль сделать **static** методы в слое бизнес-логики в spring приложении? К примеру, добавить класс

```
   class BusinessLogic{
      public static int getData(){
         //Запросы к DAO
        //Логика обработки
        return 100500; //Возврат оответа,  на основании логики
       }
    }
```

Подразумевается, что из web-слоя дальше будет вызов:

```
@GetMapping("/index")
        public String index() {
            BusinessLogic.getData(100500); //Какой-то запрос в слой бизнес-логики
            return "Hello from application"; //Здесь какой-то ответ
        }
```

Или стандартный стиль для слоя бизнес-логики какой-то другой?

Comment: Где тут слой бизнес логики? В вопросе его нету.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В нормальному пути - ваш сервис будет один единственный на все приложение обьект, автоматически созданный синглтон, который помечен аннотацией `@Autowired` при обьявлении в других классах. И вы методы будете вызывать не разных обьектов - а одного единственного, что практически выглядит так же как  Static,  учитывая что между запросами состояния не сохраняются - не преесекаются, смысла именно в static  нет, не хотите - не пользуйтесь аттрибутами класса.

То есть в контроллере будет так:

```
@Autowired
BusinessLogic businessLogic // Этот обьект вам не надо инициализировать, просто это обьявление и все. 
//Инициализация происходит автоматически одного обьекта на все приложение

@GetMapping("/index")
        public String index() {
            businessLogic.getData(100500); //Какой-то запрос в слой бизнес-логики
            return "Hello from application"; //Здесь какой-то ответ
        }
```

А в сервисе так:

```
@Service
class BusinessLogic{
      public static int getData(){
         //Запросы к DAO
        //Логика обработки
        return 100500; //Возврат ответа,  на основании логики
       }
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение. Наверное вы правы, я тоже предполагаю написать интерфейс, его реализацию, и провести @Autowired

Comment: @AndrewKachalin Да, тут нужно попахать, интерфейсы, реализация... Может без интерфейсов как-то можно обойтись?

Comment: Конечно можно, вот мой пример без интерфейсов, все базовые примеры тоже без них https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/